O(N²) Test Failing
Why do i get a Stack Overflow exception with this:
// Calling method:
OofNSq(50000);

// Method:
public static int OofNSq(int n)
{
    if (n <= 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    return n + OofNSq(n - 1);
}

n = 30728 when it is thrown. If I change n to less than 19,271 then it works. 
An INT has a size of -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647 so I'm missing something.

Each recursive call requires space on the stack. When n is 30728 it means you have a lot of nested recursive calls (almost 20000). Why do you use recursion at all for this problem ?

dotfiddle handles this as-is; https://dotnetfiddle.net/N9sOlJ but yes you're nesting calls which has a limit somewhere.

I don't think it's an int overflow...  I'm guessing it's memory since you're doing recursion.

If all you want to do is test O(n^2) can you just do two nested for loops?

A side note: your calculation of the sum 1+...+n is actually done in O(n), not O(n^2), as it requires O(n) additions.

That makes sense, so I'm throwing a Stack Overflow because of out-of-space on the stack, not because it exceeds the value of the int. So I've exceeded the max stack size in this implementation.

@Josh yes, that is the meaning of a stack overflow exception. It's not a numeric overflow.

@wohlstad - this came out a book that had a chapter on Big O, the author was saying this was O(N²) because it would take O(n) time and O(n) space (a two-dimensional array)

@Josh space and time complexities do not add up. Each has a separate complexity (O(n) in your case). And BTW the space complexity is O(n) because of the recursion. Using a loop will make space complexity O(1) (but time will still be O(n)).

OofNSq(3);, by their own logic, becomes 3 + OofNSq(2) + OofNSq(1); and if it were 4, then the addition statement likewise will become 4 parts being added. This is scaling linearly, and therefore is O(n) for efficiency. Now for space, as others have mentioned, as a result of recursion you are getting allocations for the returned value, resulting in O(n). You do not determine space and time efficiency as if they are the same, or causally linked, You evaluate each separately, and report each separately

Of course, there are common themes, if your looping for too long then yea you probably allocating too much also. But you must evaluate each separately

A summary of the information from the comments:

A stack-overflow exception is a result of exceeding stack space (which is relatively small).
It is caused by the recursive calls in your code. Each call requires space on the stack.
When you start with n==50000, then by the time you get to n==30728, you have alsmost 20000 nested recursive calls, all occupying space on the stack and you have ran out of it.

The code in question does not have complexity of O(n^2).
Time and space complexity do not add up. They are analyzed separatly.
In your case of calculating the sum 1+...+n:
Time complexity: O(n) because you have O(n) stages, each containing addition and a function call (O(1) for each such stage).
Space complexity: also O(n) due to the recursive calls occupying space on the stack as explained above.

If you change your algorithm from recursive to iterative (using a loop), the space complexity will drop to O(1) (time will still be O(n)).
It will also solve your stack-overflow exception problem.


